# Linear Model coefficient estimation

Tags: linear-model, multicollinearity

Let's assume that we have two linear models:

Linear Model 1  (LM1)     Y = B1X1 + B2X2 + e

Linear Model 2  (LM2)     Y = BX1 + e

Depending on whether X2 is independent vs. positively correlated vs. negative correlated with X1, can we say anything about whether the coefficient B in LM2 is greater/same/less than B1 in LM1?

I feel like it's not conclusive, but maybe it's because I'm new to stats

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox

Comment: What is X in LM2?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov edited